# How do I handle sql connection and data handling in razor pages with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, razor-pages

What is the "Correct" way of handling database connection and getting data from table when working in razor pages?

This setup is working just fine but what happens when a lot of users are on the site, will it get a sql connection error?, I have added the AddTransient to both the manager and sql classes and from what I can understand `AddTransient` creates a new instance of that object everytime its needed and then destroys it again

So is there a better way of handling sql connection and data handling with razor pages?

Currently I'm having this setup:

SqlDataAccess

```
 private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        public string ConnString { get; private set; }

        public SqlDataAccess(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            ConnString = _config.GetConnectionString("Default");
        }
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
                conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString);
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("query", conn);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    products.Add(new Product((string)reader["PartNumber"], (string)reader["Name"], (int)reader["Stock"], (decimal)reader["Price"]));
                }
                conn.Close();
                return products;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

ProductManager

```
 private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;
         public ProductManager(ISqlDataAccess db)
 {
     _db = db;
 }
 public List<Product> GetProducts()
 {
     return _db.GetProducts();
 }
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

     // Add services to the container.
     builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
     builder.Services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
     builder.Services.AddTransient<IProductManager, ProductManager>();
     var app = builder.Build();

     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
         // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
         app.UseHsts();
     }

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.MapRazorPages();

     app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the connection each time so you won't get any memory leaks. In fact, the connection will get returned to a connection pool for reuse to save the cost of instantiating it from new each time. So from a performance point of view, there is no issue with your approach.

As to "better" ways to manage data access, that's a matter of opinion (I would recommend use of an ORM, myself) and is likely to get your question closed ;-)